# Remove content onclick for dynamically generated buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the following code to delete messages in my website. The problem is that newly added messages (dynamically loaded) have the delete button (href links to delete message) that does not work. Is there is any solution for this?

```
  <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".remove-button").click(function() {
             alert('removed');
           });
          });
  </script>
  <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash remove-button"></span></a>
```

Comment: Yes, it is called `delegation`: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: You should bind click event handlers to new buttons, after they are added.

Comment: ...and you did not read the link provided by @putvande within 23 seconds ;-)

Comment: follow this http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When you need to bind some event handlers to dynamically added
>   elements you have to use live (deprecated) or on make the it working.
>   Simply $('element').click(...); won't work on any dynamically added
>   element in to the DOM.

Change your code

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
           $(document).on("click",".remove-button",function() {
             alert('removed');
           });
          });
  </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Please use "live" or "on" function but it is deprecated for latest jquery
$(".remove-button").live('click',function() {
  alert('removed');
});
```

Comment: If you know it is deprecated, why are you giving it as an answer? Its been deprecated since 1.7 which is years ago.